# Can't type backslash with external windows european keyboard

Tags: keyboard, mac-pro

I have a Macboock Pro with Spanish keyboard. I am using an external windows (typical Logitech's black one) keyboard and everything works fine except the backslash. In this layout (in both keyboards) the backslash is next to the 1 (and its left) and below the tab key. However, if I press it in my external keyboard (no matter if I press shift,ctrl, windows, alt, altgr+shift, altgr) I get <>≤≥. In my mac it works fine with alt + the key.
How could I solve it? Thanks

Comment: Isn’t it on the key to the left of the Z?

Comment: It is indeed. Thank you very very much

Comment: Reversal of these keys usually indicates the machine thinks the keyboard has the wrong "type", ANSI instead of ISO.  Some possible fixes are described at https://m10lmac.blogspot.com/2009/12/fixing-keyboard-type-problems.html

Comment: I have a French Logitech keyboard connected to my MBP and found setting to "pc" layout worked. Did you try that or are you using Apple layout?

Comment: @lx07 Unlike for French, there is no "pc" input source for Spanish.